# np.zeros(dim,1) giving datatype not understood

Tags: numpy

I am very new to python and numpy. I'm trying to initialize a Row Vector with zeros as follows:

```
w = np.zeros(dim,1)
```

I'm getting the error `TypeError: data type not understood`. I appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: Pass in a tuple: `np.zeros((dim,1))`

Answer (score 7):

See the documentation on [np.zeros](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html)

If you call it the way you did, the size is `dim`, and the data type argument `dtype` is `1`, which is not a valid data type.

The solution is

```
import numpy as np
dim = 3 # number of entries
shp = (dim, 1) # shape tuple
x = np.zeros(shp) # second argument 'dtype' is not used, default is 'float'
print(x)
```

Comment: Thanks for this response. Tried the above mentioned solution. But it didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You should call is like:

```
w = np.zeros((dim, 1))
```

Based on the docs:

```
numpy.zeros(shape, dtype=float, order='C')
```

In this case (dim,1) is the shape